# Get Payload in Dialog Participant Step

Tags: aem

I want to get payload inside dialog participant step in CQ5 under my widget's listener. Below id my dialog.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
    <jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0" jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog" title="Changetemplate" xtype="dialog">
    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <Template jcr:primaryType="cq:Panel">
            <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                <Path jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" fieldLabel="Select Template" id="mytemplate" name="./jcr:content/templatepath" xtype="textfield">
                  <listeners jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" afterrender="function(component){ var dialog = CQ.wcm.showTemplate('/content/geometrixx/en'); dialog.show(); }" /> 
                </Path>
            </items>
        </Template>
    </items>
    </jcr:root>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the help of following code in java.

```
public class MyParticipant implements ParticipantStepChooser {

    @Property(value = "An example.")
    static final String DESCRIPTION = Constants.SERVICE_DESCRIPTION; 
    @Property(value = "MyComapany")
    static final String VENDOR = Constants.SERVICE_VENDOR;
    @Property(value = " Participant Chooser Process")
    static final String LABEL=ParticipantStepChooser.SERVICE_PROPERTY_LABEL;

    private static final String TYPE_JCR_PATH = "JCR_PATH";

    public String getParticipant(WorkItem workItem, WorkflowSession workflowSession, MetaDataMap args) throws WorkflowException {
        WorkflowData workflowData = workItem.getWorkflowData();
        if (workflowData.getPayloadType().equals(TYPE_JCR_PATH)) {
            String path = workflowData.getPayload().toString();

        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

In ecma script

```
var workflowData = graniteWorkItem.getWorkflowData();
    if (workflowData.getPayloadType() == "JCR_PATH") { 
        var path = workflowData.getPayload().toString(); }
```

but if you want to get that path in the dialog specifically  try 
1. `CQ.utils.WCM.getPagePath();`

If above solutions doesn't solve your problem then

1. create a servlet
2. Hit that servlet from the dialog and get the payload(mostly current path) in that servlet.
   refer to [this](http://www.citytechinc.com/us/en/blog/2012/04/complex_cq5_dialog_validation.html) url for reference.